# Template overload resolution for operators inside an anonymous namespace

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup

**Short question:** do operators have special template lookup rules for overload resolution with internal linkage or is the code at the bottom a template overload resolution bug for operators in GCC?

**The detail:** instead of pasting a chunk of code I'll take you through my reasoning. Let's start with some simple code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct A{ T b; };
struct B{};

template<typename T> 
void foo (const A<T>&a) { foo(a.b); } 
void foo (const B&) { std::cout << "hello"; }

int main(){
  A<B> b;
  foo(b);
}
```

The above prints `"hello"`, everything is fine.

Now let's put both `foo` in an anonymous namespace:

```
namespace {
template<typename T> 
void foo (const A<T>&a) { foo(a.b); } 
void foo (const B&) { std::cout << "hello"; }
}
```

The code now fails to compile. Clang says `error: call to function 'foo' that is neither visible in the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup` and GCC `template argument deduction/substitution failed`.

This is broken because `foo(const B&)` is defined after `foo<T>` and doesn't have an external linkage, as explained in [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf):

> *[basic.link]*
>   An unnamed namespace or a namespace declared directly or indirectly within an unnamed namespace has
>   internal linkage. All other namespaces have external linkage.
>
> *[temp.point]*
>   The instantiation context of an expression that depends on the template arguments is the set of declarations
>   *with external linkage declared prior to the point of instantiation* of the template specialization in the same translation unit.
>
> *[temp.dep.candidate]*
>   For a function call where the postfix-expression is a dependent name,
>   the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1,
>   3.4.2) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), only function declarations from the template
>     definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using
>     associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations found in
>     either the template definition context or the template instantiation
>     context are found.

Now the same thing using operators:

```
struct ostream {} cout; 
template<typename T> struct A{ T t; };
struct B{};

namespace {
template<typename T>
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const A<T>&v) 
  { return out << v.t; }
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const B&) 
  { return out; }
}

int main(){
  A<B> a;
  cout << a; 
}
```

GCC (4.7/4.8/4.9) is now perfectly happy with the code and gives zero warning with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic -ansi` while clang complains about `'operator<<'` the same way it did for `foo`.

I didn't find any exception for operator overload lookup in the standard so I believe this is a bug (feature?) in GCC but template resolution rules are not easy so I thought I might check here before filing a bug.

You can see this code live [here](http://ideone.com/AQkRdN).

Comment: Possibly related to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51577

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @T.C. There is indeed something screwy about operator lookup in GCC.  I will still file it as a separate bug since the context seems different enough but the root cause might be the same.

Comment: I got the `foo` code to compile on GCC by switching the order of the definitions. Does that match what you'd expect? Here's [my fork of your live example](http://ideone.com/HBFsO4).

Comment: @AustinMullins : Yes, it does. The point here is that the example with `foo` is ill-formatted according to the standard, and it should be as well for the `operator<<`, but it isn't (for gcc). Your fix for the code is correct, and clang even tells you what to do if you try to compile the example above: `'foo' should be declared prior to the call site or in the global namespace`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely a bug in gcc. The code below rightly prints `right` with clang but `wrong` with GCC.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> struct A{ T t; };
struct B{};
struct C : public B{};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const B&) 
  { return out << "right"; }

namespace {
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const A<T>&v) 
  { return out << v.t; }

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const C&) 
  { return out << "wrong"; }
}

int main(){
  A<C> a;
  std::cout << a;
}
```

Reported [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=65336).